# Convert C# object to DynamoDB json

Tags: c#, json, amazon-dynamodb

I have C# object

```
Step1Members step1Members = new Step1Members()
                    {                            
                        businessName =  "Test business",
                        contactName = "Test User"
                    };
```

I want to convert step1Members into DynamoDB json like below.

{"businessName" : { "S" : "Test business" }, "contactName" : { "S" : "Test User" }}

Please help me on this.

Comment: I do not know how DynamoDB works... but if all you need is a json string why no use Newtonsoft JSON??

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Newtonsoft will not work because dynamodb json is little different than normal json.

Comment: you can use aws sdk for .net https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DotNetSDKHighLevel.html

Answer (score 1):

You can actually do it using the [EfficientDynamoDb](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EfficientDynamoDb).

Based on your example, let's imagine you have a class like this:

```
public class Step1Members
{
    [DynamoDbProperty("businessName")]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    
    [DynamoDbProperty("contactName")]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
}
```

In order to generate a DynamoDb JSON, you need to:

```
// Create DynamoDb context, credentials are not required for JSON generation, only for real database calls
var context = new DynamoDbContext(new DynamoDbContextConfig(RegionEndpoint.EUCenteral1, new AwsCredentials("public_key", "private_key")));

var step1Members = new Step1Members()
{                            
    BusinessName =  "Test business",
    ContactName = "Test User"
};

await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await using var jsonWriter = new Utf8JsonWriter(memoryStream);

// Convert a class object into the document
var document = context.ToDocument(step1Members);
     
// Write the document using Utf8JsonWriter
jsonWriter.WriteStartObject();
foreach (var attribute in document)
{
    jsonWriter.WritePropertyName(attribute.Key);
    attribute.Value.Write(jsonWriter);
}
jsonWriter.WriteEndObject();
jsonWriter.Flush();

// Read the final JSON string from the memory stream
var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

If you don't want to create a C# class for every single use-case, you can just use the plain `Document` class, which is basically a dictionary.